# SQL to count the total number for distinct values in a column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am looking for a query which will return the number of rows for each distinct value in a column.

Consider the following table -

[image]

I want to query for total number of rows for all distinct DoBs. I expect the following output-

[image]

`SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT DoB::date) AS Person_Count FROM TableName`

Comment: You need to `GROUP BY`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
SELECT DoB::date, count(1) AS Person_Count FROM TableName

GROUP BY DoB::date
```

Answer (score 0):

What you've written aggregates every row in the table together, which means that you'll only ever get one row back in the results.  *(Then, `COUNT(DISTINCT DoB)` tells you how many different DoB's there are in that single group.)*

You need to specify that you want to aggregate the rows in to groups, where each group is identified by the date of birth; giving one output row per different DoB in your table.  Then you can use `COUNT(*)` to return the number of rows in each group.

```
SELECT
  DoB,
  COUNT(*)   AS person_count
FROM
  table_name
GROUP BY
  DoB
ORDER BY
  DoB
```